Newb in Linux needs help with partition and space
I'm a beginner in Arch Linux (I know it's not the best distro to start with but I think one learns more when everything is broken).
I think I've made a mistake in the installation of Arch - the partitions are wrong? - because whenever I install something it gets installed in a little partition of 23.0 GiB but I have another partition of 214 GiB. My question/problem is: How to move the things or make the 23GiB bigger.
This is the output of fdisk -l :
Disk /dev/nvme0n1: 238.47 GiB, 256060514304 bytes, 500118192 sectors
Disk model: BC711 NVMe SK hynix 256GB               
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: D296046A-B417-403B-A3AF-CBEB7038E791

Device            Start       End   Sectors   Size Type
/dev/nvme0n1p1     2048   2099199   2097152     1G EFI System
/dev/nvme0n1p2  2099200  50333695  48234496    23G Linux root (x86-64)
/dev/nvme0n1p3 50333696 500116143 449782448 214.5G Linux filesystem


Disk /dev/zram0: 2.84 GiB, 3047161856 bytes, 743936 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 4096 = 4096 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Please add output from running fdisk -l (as root)

This is likely the result of the typical newbie mistake of overpartitioning. Yes, everything other then user settings is installed in the root/system partition and 23GB is kinda small for current standards. You'd better install without a separated /home partition.

Never reinstall arch. (Maybe if you destroy all your partitions)
